# Page Refresh JS

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get my page to refresh if a field in the database changes.

I can get the JS to check every half second (speed for debugging) but it does not change value without refreshing the page, what should I be researching for this?

```
        SetInterval(function() {
            $.get('./include/update.php', function(data) {
                var d = "<?php echo $pageNumFinal; ?>";
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = d;
                if(d !== data) {
                    document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = data;
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }, 500);
```

**update.php**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pagenum FROM display WHERE id=1");
$stmt->execute();

$pageNumCount=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$pageNumFinal = $pageNumCount['pagenum'];
```

Comment: `location.reload();` is telling the browser to reload the page...

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't reloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: Updated my answer following [our conversation in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156140/discussion-between-justcarty-and-sauced-apples).

You are passing an argument data to the anonymous function, but are also declaring a variable called data and comparing them. Change the name of one of them at least.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('./include/update.php', function(data) {
        var d = "<?php echo $pageNumFinal; ?>";
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data;

        if (d !== data) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}, 500);
```

Also, where you set the variable (`d`) you are trying to set it to `$pageNumFinal` which is a variable you set in update.php.
Make sure that in your file that contains this script you are getting the current page number and storing it in that variable which will get printed at run time and stored into `d`.

Comment: Thank you for this, it appears the `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data;` was messing it up.

Comment: I'm noticing this just seems to be refreshing regardless of the variable having a different value or not, can this be fixed?

Comment: can you console.log(d) and console.log(data) and tell me what the results are?

Comment: Also what is `#test`?

Comment: I was using it to output the values held in the variables but  console.log works too.  They have been removed some time ago

Comment: The reason `data` is empty is because nothing is being outputted from the update.php script. Echo `$pageNumFinal` and then `data` will be set. As for the variable `d` that should be getting the current data (or page number or whatever it is that the code does).

Comment: It's only refreshing so quick because I didn't want to wait long to see if it is working.  This isn't a form it is looking to see if a value has changed to trigger the page to refresh only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156140/discussion-between-justcarty-and-sauced-apples).

Comment: Thank you for your help on this one!

Comment: @SaucedApples Happy to have helped :)